# NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0 and Nunit 3.11 does not discover tests in Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, nunit, vstest, nunittestadapter

I have written test scripts in VS2017 which run using NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0  and Nunit 3.11 
locally/test explorer, but when I want to run the same tests in Azure pipelines I get the below 
error, not sure what this error is pointing to?

Starting test execution, please wait...
Information: NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution started

Information: Running all tests in D:\AgentsP\B41ORIS1_work\125\a\some.dll

> Warning: Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException, Exception thrown
>   executing tests in D:\AgentsP\B41ORIS1_work\125\a\some.dll Warning:
>   An exception occurred in the driver while loading tests. Information:
>   NUnit Adapter 3.8.0.0: Test execution complete Warning: No test is
>   available in D:\AgentsP\B41ORIS1_work\125\a\some.dll. Make sure that
>   installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version
>   settings are appropriate and try again.

**and here is my package .config**

```
<package id="NUnit" version="3.11.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.8.0" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="RhinoMocks" version="3.6.1" targetFramework="net452" />
      <package id="SpecFlow" version="3.1.97" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="SpecFlow.NUnit" version="3.1.97" targetFramework="net461" />
      <package id="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" version="3.1.97" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest version of the NUnit and NUnit3TestAdapter packages?

Comment: @Chris I have tried NUnit = 3.11 and NUnit3TestAdapter =3.16,using latest adapter is giving me the error "Could not load nunit.framework.dll 3.11 reference"

Comment: @Chris upgrading to latest NunitAdapter works successfully on my local machine, but on the Azure pipelines it fails with the below error Innerexception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.11.0.0,